# Using NSKeyedArchiver throw Exception:[NSConcreteValue length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried to use NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver.The code throw exception: "[NSConcreteValue length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance".

```
@interface DBTLine() <NSCoding>
@end
@implementation DBTLine

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeCGPoint:self.begin forKey:@"begin"];
    [aCoder encodeCGPoint:self.end forKey:@"end"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.color forKey:@"color"];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
  //Throw Exception Here.
        _begin = [coder decodeCGPointForKey:@"begin"];
        _end = [coder decodeCGPointForKey:@"end"];
        _color = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"color"];
    }
    return self;
}
@end

@interface DBTDrawView()
@property (nonatomic)NSMutableArray *finishedLines;
@end
@implementation DBTDrawView
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSData* dataFinishedLines = [defaults objectForKey:@"finishedLines"];
        NSMutableArray *defaultLines = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataFinishedLines];
        if (defaultLines) {
            self.finishedLines = defaultLines;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //some code,"self.finishedLines" add line
    NSData *dataFinishedLines = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.finishedLines];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:dataFinishedLines forKey:@"finishedLines"];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
@end
```

I searched the Internet for a long time,and I've tried multiple variations of my code.Finally,It works.Here is my changed code:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    NSValue *begin = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.begin];
    NSValue *end = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.end];
    [aCoder encodeObject:begin forKey:@"begin"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:end forKey:@"end"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.color forKey:@"color"];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSValue *begin = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"begin"];
        NSValue *end = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"end"];
        _begin = [begin CGPointValue];
        _end = [end CGPointValue];
        _color = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"color"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

But the problem is:

1. It seems the problem appeared in the process of using "-
   encodeCGPoint:forKey: - decodeCGPointForKey:".Was there anything
   wrong with what I did?
2. What is "[NSConcreteValue length]"?I can't find it in the document.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2.: `NSConcreteValue` is the inner class name of `NSValue` (let's says it's one of its various private name). What's appending, is that somewhere, it's calling the method `length`, and it doesn't have it (it may have thought it was a `NSString` and called internally `length`).
1.: Did you modify the encoding/decoding between two attempts? Could be the issue. Try to remove the app from the device, and try again withe `encodeCGPoint:forKey:` `decodeCGPointForKey:`.

Comment: @Larme Thank you for your answer sincerely.You are right.I modified the code.So, I think it  `NSValue *begin = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.begin];[aCoder encodeObject:begin forKey:@"begin"];` first,and then `[coder decodeCGPointForKey:@"begin"];`

Comment: @Larme You have awesome estimation.Have you seen the same problem?Or have some skills?I want to learn more.Thank you.

Comment: I learnt how to debug by facing crashes, and understanding the reasons. "unrecognized selector" is a well known error, once you understand why it's a lot easier. I also, used encoding/decoding, so it's just habit/experience. So it's just logic, memory, and intuitions. Combine them all, you should be fine.

Comment: @Larme Well,thank you again.That's very sweet of you.